# Eclipse project runtime problems

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I have 2 projects Dynamic Web project XYZ and another java project ABC 
I have added project reference of ABC in XYZ from java build path of XYZ and also added ABC jar in XYZ `web-inf/lib` folder.

Now, when I am running XYZ on server the changes done in ABC are not reflecting i.e.,
I have written many `System.out.println` in ABC but it is not printing anything on console while running XYZ on server ,I have also tried adding latest jar of ABC in XYZ but it looks worthless. I am unable to check from where XYZ project is reading Class files of ABC.

Answer (score 0):

You should have warned about *cyclic dependencies*. Consider to refactor to the several modules that don't have it. Or, export to jar and add it to the project. In that case better to use *Maven* to place a jar to the repository and reference other projects.